# Android App Individual Developer Privacy Policy compliance

Tags: android, privacy-policy

I developed my own Android App for Google Play Store(not released). I am an individual developer. I need to add a privacy policy required by the Google Play Store. I am based in USA.

My app does not collect any user data, there are no push notifications, and there are no login screens.

Issue: Privacy Policy generator software creates a Policy with a business entity perspective while Google Play Console allows to upload apps created by Business and Individual Developer.

I don't know the proper way for an individual developer to generate the appropriate Privacy Policy while most Privacy Generator tools are geared towards a business entity.

Could I just say 'Home' for a business name if I am an individual developer?

I am not sure about what info I should provide like my private cell phone number and fax number for an individual developer. This information comes from Privacy Policy Generator Software, not from Google.

Google requires Privacy Policy compliance for all types of developers including business entity and non-business or individual developer.

Based on the information found from Privacy Policy generator software, the app policy should be compliant with: General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA), Children's Online Privacy Protection Rule (COPPA), and The California Online Privacy Protection Act (CalOPPA).

I need feedback what Privacy Policy I should have being individual developer.

Do I need to create a website for my Privacy Policy being individual developer or adding an empty repo on Github will be sufficient?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are not exempt from privacy laws just because you are a person rather than an organization [1].

You can include a Privacy Policy similar to those for companies, but adapt it to mention that the data controller is an individual instead of a company.

Your Privacy Policy URL needs to be publicly available, there's no requirement where to store it (i.e. GitHub, Google Drive, own website etc.).

[1] https://www.termsfeed.com/blog/privacy-policy-individual/